# Unrecognized configuration section compilation

Tags: c#, configuration

I am getting a Unrecognized configuration section compilation exception when adding

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
.....

  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
    <assemblies>
      <add assembly="System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
    </assemblies>
  </compilation>
```

this to my app.config

how do I add this to an app.config associated with a windows service?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`<compilation>` must be a child of the `<system.web>` element - see more info at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s10awwz0.aspx.

Comment: how do I add this to an app.config associated with a windows service?